# Jquery Mobile: Disable Button Style Wise & Function Wise Button Until after an event occurrs

Tags: jquery-mobile

So as many know JQM mobile does some auto rendering to links to make them button like in appearance. I read a couple of items on here and they are bit out of date so I have a particular issue I'm trying to solve right this moment.

I have a basic button like such.

`< a href="#" id="icon-test" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-icon="custom" class="ui-disabled">Go On`

I need to disable this button in both function & visual style. I attempted to use just a simple ui-disabled on the a href but of course that only disables the visual aspect not the functional aspect of this link (button). This became apparent when running some tests in windows phone 7.5

I'm assuming I need to add something to one of our default page init events. Any help is appreciated.  I need to make sure this is a a href type button as the data-icon="custom" has a lot of styling that allows for some pretty cool flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a totally different visual, perhaps creating a dummy link be an option for you here? For eg:

```
<a href="#" id="icon-test" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-icon="custom" id='real'>
    Go On 
</a>
<span id='fake'>Go On</span>
```

On pageinit:

```
$('#real').hide();
$('#fake').show();
```

And on the special event:

```
$('#real').show();
$('#fake').hide();
```

---

Otherwise if you need the same styling but no functionality, you could try disabling the link by adding onclick handler:

```
<a href="#" id="icon-test" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-icon="custom" id='real' onclick="return false;">
    Go On 
</a>
```

Comment: No don't that would work - I think I need a function that is part of the init - to disable the button function so it can't be clicked or a click on the disabled button would cause the event to be ignored - until the button is in an active state.

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understood properly, but you might need to add the following attribute to your a (link): onclick="return false;"